# Calculating amount of Sylow 2-subgroups in $S_5$ by using the amounts of 3- and 5- subgroups?

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

So I am supposed to calculate the amount of 2-,3- and 5-Sylow subgroups in $S_5$ and I already calculated that the amount for 3 and 5 are 10 and 6. So can I use this to drag myself over the finish line and imply that there really are 15 Sylow 2-subgroups or do I need to come up with a completely new proof again? We didn't do much on the symmetric and dihedral groups so I am struggling a little bit to figure out how to get a proof for Sylow 2-subgroups.

Comment: The Sylow $2$-subgroups fix a unique point, so if you can show that $S_4$ has $3$ Sylow 2-subgroups, then $S_5$ has $5 \times 3 = 15$.

Comment: Hey Derek thx for the answer! What do you mean with fixing a unique point?

Comment: Well, for example, there is a Sylow $2$-subgroup $S$ of $S_5$ that is generated by the permutations $(2,3,4,5)$ and $(3,5)$, and $S$ fixes the unique point $1$.

Comment: oh yeah you are right! thx a lot. I get it now... That's a really cool way to solve this :)